# Python script execution stops when performing multiple PyODBC sql queries

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to write a loop that runs over multiple tables in a database, stores the result in a dataframe and then writes that dataframe to an excel workbook. However, even though I have 29 tables in my list, my code execution stops after a small amount (and is inconsistent, sometimes it stops after 1 query, but usually it will stop 5-6 queries in). Any ideas as to why that is?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=XXXX")
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-16-le')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-16-le')
conn.setencoding(encoding='utf-16-le')
TABLES = ['Table1', 'Table2', ..., 'Table29']

def query_multiple_tables(tables: list[str]) -> list[pd.DataFrame]:
    dataframes = []
    for table in tables:
        QUERY = f"SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[{table}]"
        col_crsr = conn.cursor()
        data_crsr = conn.cursor()
        
        cols = [row.column_name for row in col_crsr.columns(table=f"{table}")]
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_crsr.execute(QUERY).fetchmany(20), columns=cols)
        
        print(f"Extracting table: {table}")
        dataframes.append(data)

        col_crsr.close()
        data_crsr.close()
    
    return dataframes

def write_to_excel(dataframes: list[pd.DataFrame]) -> None:
    
    try:
        with pd.ExcelWriter("Data.xlsx", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
            for i, dataframe in enumerate(dataframes):
                dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{i}')
                print(f"Append successful for: {i}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        with pd.ExcelWriter("Data.xlsx", mode='w') as writer:
            for i, dataframe in enumerate(dataframes):
                dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{i}')
                print(f"Initial write successful for: {i}")

data = query_multiple_tables(FIA_TABLES)
write_to_excel(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The results will get put into a df 'query' and loop and join into a master df then you can put that into a csv/xlsx

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
connection = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection)
connection = engine.connect() 
df = pd.DataFrame()
Tables = ['1', '2'....]
for table in Tables:
   query = f'''
   select * from {table}
'''
   query = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
   df = pd.concat(df, query)
```

Comment: The problem is that all tables contain different columns/data. So concatanating doesn't really work, and i would like to have all tables in a separate tab in the workbook.

Comment: then as opposed to the concat, you could have that be the write to the workbook on a new tab.

Comment: What is the point of URL.create? I think you are missing an sqlalchemy import in your code, since it doesn't seem to be a built-in function of python? The problem is not connecting to the database, I have managed to get the query to run, but it stops abruptly after 4-5 queries